# Calculate average of an specific data that can be neutral

Tags: c#, linq, average

I've searched about how Average lambda expression exactly works, but couldn't find.

My problem is: I have some sentiment classification that is represented by diferent ways. For example, positive sentences are represented by a number > than 0. It could be from 1 to infinite (1, 2, 5, 100....) and for negative sentences the same way, but represented by a number < than 0 (-1, -2.....) - I know that isn't the better way to represent that.

And I need to calculate the positive occurrence average. Every answer from the questions on SOF I have found here, if I sum all values and divide by the total amount I will find the average. That's ok.

For example, if I had 11 sentences and 10 are positive with value = 1, (sum = 10) and one sentence negative with value = -10 my average is going to be: 10-10/ 11 = 0.

```
var average = context.CatchDetails.Where(x => x.Monitoring.Client.Id == custmrid
            && x.Data.published >= datai2
            && x.Data.published <= dataf2
            && x.Monitoring.id == monitoring).ToList().Average(y => y.Sentiment);
```

What I am doing is, taking all positive sentences (count) and dividing by the total sentences (count). Example:

total count = 11
positive count = 10

10 / 11 = 0.9090 that is 90,90% positive occurrences.

```
var positive = context.CatchDetails.Count(x => (x.Monitoring.Client.Id == custmrid)
            && x.Data.published >= datai2 && x.Data.published <= dataf2
            && x.Monitoring.id == monitoring
            && x.Sentiment > 0);

var total = context.CatchDetails.Count(x => (x.Monitoring.Client.Id == custmrid)
           && x.Data.published >= datai2 && x.Data.published <= dataf2
           && x.Monitoring.id == monitoring);

double mediaPositive = ((double)positive / (double)total);
```

Is there any better possibility for doing that?

Searches:

[How to get words average length using Lambda Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533555/how-to-get-words-average-length-using-lambda-expression)

[Getting an average from a C# array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700904/getting-an-average-from-a-c-sharp-array/30700933#30700933)

Comment: Why don't u simply divide the sum of all positive and negative values by the number of items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the data passed from one LINQ operator to another:

```
var avg = data.Select(x => x.Sentiment > 0 ? x.Sentiment : 0)
              .Average();
```

So treat all negative values as zero.

Alternately if you want to just ignore the value of some items, but still include them in the count, you'll need to do the average calculation yourself.

```
var count = data.Count();
var total = data.Select(x => x.Sentiment > 0).Sum(x => x.Sentiment);
// Avoid divide by zero if no data...
var avg = count > 0 ? total/count : defaultValue;
```

However, you seem to to just want two different counts:

```
var totalCount = data.Count();
var positiveCount = data.Select(x => x.Sentiment > 0).Count();
// Ignore totalCount == 0! But force floating point calc.
var res = (double)positiveCount / totalCount;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I could manipulate data passed from one LINQ operator to another. Solved my problem.